# Service or Scheduled Task for software updates?

Tags: windows-services, scheduled-tasks, auto-update

I'm currently designing a software updater application that I want to use for my own applications. Since the update itself usually requires administrator privileges (writing to Program Files etc.) I'd like to have something available that runs as Administrator or SYSTEM itself. I'm fully aware of my due diligence on validating the files I download and run automatically. I'll be using strong hashes and digital signatures for that.

What I'm more curious about is whether to use a Windows Service or the Windows Task Scheduler for the regular update checking.

Here's what I've found so far:

- Google uses a scheduled task that regularly checks for updates. It is accompanied by a service that supposedly runs the updates or so. Both, task and service, run as SYSTEM and are started on-demand. The service is usually stopped and cannot be controlled by a normal user. Updates are checked and installed at any time in the background.
- Mozilla Firefox uses a service that is probably started by the browser when it's downloaded something to install. The service is started on-demand, runs as SYSTEM, and regular users are allowed to start and stop the service. Updates are only checked when the app runs.
- Other applications just check, download and execute as regular user. The update itself will then ask for UAC. Updates are only checked when the app runs.

The Google approach seems most desirable to me, but I don't know whether I need the additional service at all. Actually I believe it should be enough to set up a scheduled task, started as SYSTEM, that will check, download and run the update. Since everything is in the SYSTEM (or maybe also the Administrator) context, it should be reasonably safe against "user vandalism"...

Is my design good enough or will I run into problems with the scheduled task alone?